# How can i add $5 Handling fee if free shipping method is selected?

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods

I need to add $5 Handling Fee if Free Shipping method is selected.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add this charge as extra Fee, right?

Comment: Yes, I need this Handling fee as extra charge just in case of Free Shipping

Comment: This module may be useful to you https://fooman.com/magento-extension-shipping-surcharge-m2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin name="{Your_Plugin_Name}" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin\Freeshipping" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin File

> Freeshipping.php

```
class Freeshipping
{
    protected $rateResultFactory;
    protected $rateMethodFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    }

    public function afterCollectRates(\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject, $result)
    {
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $shippingPrice = "5.00"; //custom price

        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($subject->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
        $method->setMethodTitle($subject->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

        $result->append($method);
        return $result;
    }
}
```